# Percent difference between 2 tables with matching IDs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZALF.jpg

In the image, I have 2 tables. I would like to find the percent difference between "pops" if the CMA_IDs match So basically, cma_Id matches in both tables, I would like to write a formula that says, if the cma in table 1, matches the cma in table 2, then find the percent difference for pops

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried an IF statement, but its not consistent

Comment: You need to explain what you expect as a result for certain data (not being screenshot)

Comment: @P.b in the image, i need to find the percent difference for pops between the 2 tables with matching cma_id. I need a formula that tells me IF cma_id is located in table 2, then to find the percent difference in pops.

Comment: Look into VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH and use that for the percentage calculation.